# I am trying to extract Track ID from Spotify, my inputs are Artist name and track name

Tags: python

I am trying to get access to Spotify's API

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials  # To access authorised Spotify data

client_id = ""
client_secret = ""
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(
    client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret
)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth="TOKEN")
artist = "Moses Sumney"
track = "Lonely World"
track_id = sp.search(q="artist:" + artist + " track:" + track, type="track")
trackId = track_id["tracks"]["items"][0]["id"]
```

I am getting the error:

> HTTP Error for GET to https://api.spotify.com/v1/search returned 401 due to
> Invalid access token"

I have `client_id` and `client_secret`, how can I make this work?

Comment: I don't see that you're supplying an access token in your request.  Also, you create a `SpotifyClientCredentials` object, but don't do anything with it, so you aren't doing anything with your credentials either. - If you're asking us to help you learn how to call the Spotify API, well that's not what Stack Overflow is about.  I'm sure there's already documentation out there to show you how to do that.